# Chef's remote_file with local file source

Tags: chef-infra

I am using Chef 11.4.4, and have a cookbook excerpt:

```
remote_file "test" do
  source "file:///home/user/myfile.rpm"
  action :create
end
```

When running I got following error:
Connection refused - Connection refused connecting to : for /home/user/myfile.rpm/file:///home/user/myfile.rpm, giving up

What is going on? How can source for local file?

Comment: resource `remote_file` supports local file via `file:///foo/bar`. it should work very well. the problem is I'm not sure if it can access files under a user home directory.

Comment: @shawnzshu, The error message is quite cumbersome. It tells that it tries to access some strange url I've never setup: "/home/user/myfile.rpm/file:///home/user/myfile.rpm". The rights for the file are: -rwxrwxrwx 1 vagrant vagrant, and the rights for the upstream dir are: drwxr-xr-x   1 vagrant vagrant

Answer (score 0):

The "file" resource is like "remote_file" but for local files. You can find the full documentation here: https://docs.chef.io/resource_file.html

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that version *11.4.4*. I had this same problem more than once with images in older projects (for anyone one else that might end up here with same error message with the mangle file:// URL). I know this problem does not seem to exist in *11.16.4+*.

Answer (score 0):

The best method for fetching a file locally would be use "**file resource**", rather than a remote_file.

You can use this by creating a .pem file as you want in a textedit pad, and copy it to the **files** directory of the particular cookbook in which you are writing the recipe to create this particular file with the content. By this, the cookbook will look into the "files" directory of the particular cookbook and create the same file which you had copied there earlier.

For more references, you can go through this : https://docs.chef.io/resource_file.html

Hope this helps.

Thanks & regards.

Akshay